# Assign a keymap to a key in Emacs

Tags: emacs, key, keymapping, keymaps

Is there way in Emacs to assign a key to a keymap with all its bindings? I used to do following:

```
(defvar my-new-map)
(define-prefix-command 'my-new-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-~") my-new-map)
(cl-loop for code being the key-code of flyspell-mode-map
         using (key-bindings b)
         do
         (define-key my-new-map (vector code) b))
```

This creates a new keymap  `my-new-map` with desired bindings. I would like to just assign `C-~` to a `flyspell-mode-map` without creating a new keymap. Is it possible ?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate question, but I haven't found the duplicate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; you do exactly what you're doing now, just without creating and populating the new keymap.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-~") flyspell-mode-map)
```

will assign `flyspell-mode-map` to that key binding.

Comment: EvgeniySharapov: Note that `C-h f define-key` tells you this.